# When a ball is dropped on a floor is that harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, collision, projectile, oscillators

From Simple Harmonic Motion, we conclude that acceleration is proportional to its distance and the sign is negative. We also know that at equilibrium position $dU/dx=0$.
Now, if we think a ball is bouncing back and forth on a floor where no energy is dissipated, and acceleration $g$ is fixed in its way, then, will this be a harmonic motion? (Since, acceleration is not proportional to distance.) What will be its equilibrium position?

Answer (score 1):

Simple harmonic motion requires the forces to follow Hooke's Law. While the object is in the air, the force is the gravitational force, which is approximately constant (so it doesn't depend on the distance from anything, so there's no equilibrium position). When the ball is in contact with the ground, the force exerted by the ground will be approximately like Hooke's Law, to the extent that the compression of the ground can be modeled as a spring, but it won't undergo SHM, because it then leaves the ground after bouncing.

Comment: I understood that it's not SHM. Is it any type of harmonic motion rather than simple?

Answer (score 0):

No, a ball bouncing up and down on a floor isn't simple harmonic motion. As you pointed out yourself, this is because the gravitational force on the ball is always acting downwards whereas in simple harmonic motion, the force on the object is proportional to the displacement of the object and is always directed towards the equilibrium position (opposite to the displacement from the equilibrium position).

Now, for the equilibrium position of this ball, it is pretty clear that there is no permanent equilibrium position as the ball keeps bouncing. But when the ball collides with the floor, the normal force on the ball due to the ground keeps growing until it reaches a maximum and then decreases (this happens almost instantly) and while this happens there might be an instant where the normal force on the ball is equal in magnitude to the gravitational force on it and at that instant the ball will be in it's equilibrium position, momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple harmonic motion, because $g$ is constant above the surface.

But if the experience is some meters below, as in a subway for example, the gravity acceleration is: $$a = -\frac{4}{3}\pi G\rho r$$ where $r$ is the distance to the center (and $\rho$ is the average density) of the Earth. Now, the acceleration is proportional to the distance, and each cycle between bouncings is a SHM. But the oscillations as a whole, with its frequency and period are not. It is like a pendulum forced to bounce close to its maximum amplitude, instead of being allowed to complete all the cycle.